# Java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace any one of these chars:

```
% \ , [ ] # & @ ! ^
```

... with empty string ("").

I used this code:

```
String line = "[ybi-173]";
Pattern cleanPattern = Pattern.compile("%|\\|,|[|]|#|&|@|!|^");
Matcher matcher = cleanPattern.matcher(line);
line = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

But it doesn't work.

What do I miss in this regular expression?

Comment: You probably need to escape all the special characters, not just `\`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several reasons why your solution doesn't work.

Several of the characters you wish to match have special meanings in regular expressions, including `^`, `[`, and `]`. These must be escaped with a `\` character, but, to make matters worse, the `\` itself must be escaped so that the Java compiler will pass the `\` through to the regular expression constructor. So, to sum up step one, if you wish to match a `]` character, the Java string must look like `"\\]"`.

But, furthermore, this is a case for character classes `[]`, rather than the alternation operator `|`. If you want to match "any of the characters `a`, `b`, `c`, that looks like `[abc]`. You character class would be `[%\,[]#&@!^]`, but, because of the Java string escaping rules and the special meaning of certain characters, your regex will be `[%\\\\,\\[\\]#&@!\\^]`.

Comment: It is incredible that people put up with evil monstrosities like `[%\\\\,\\\[\\\]#&@!\\^]`. Truly incredible! There has **got** to be a better way!!

Comment: I was thinking the same about the `^` but it seems it only has special meaning at the beginning of the character class, and doesn't need escaping at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the characters are special characters that are being interpreted differently. You can either escape them all with backslashes, or better yet put them in a character class (no need to escape the non-CC characters, eases readability):

```
Pattern cleanPattern = Pattern.compile("[%\\\\,\\[\\]#&@!^]");
```

Comment: you'll have to escape the literal `[` and `]` in the char class.

Answer (score 0):

You'd define your pattern as a character group enclosed in `[` and `]` and escape special chars, e.g.

```
String n = "%\\,[]#&@!^".replaceAll("[%\\\\,\\[\\]#&@!^]", "");
```